# Connection Pooling

Tags: connection, pooling

May I know if the connection pooling is applicable also for the window base application and not just for web base? Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you accept few answers and give our friends some credit for spending time to answer your questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly, everything that needs a connection might pool it. No matter if it is headlesss or a GUI application.

Answer (score 2):

Connection pooling is applicable any time you will have multiple consumers contending for expensive-to-create connections.

Comment: which is probably less the case for a single user desktop application.